# {$A°, Fr(A),(X-A)°$} is partition of metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

could you help me with the following problem please:

Prove that if $A$ is a subset of a metric space $(X, d)$, then the

{$A°, Fr(A),(X-A)°$}

family forms a partition of space X. Where $A°$={$x\in A| x$ it's inside $A$}, and $Fr(A)$ denotes the border of $A$

I am a little confused, I have tried it for the definitions of each of the sets and it is evident to me, but I do not know how to write it to make it a formal demonstration

Comment: What are the definitions of "inside" and "border"?

Comment: (this for the inside) A point is said to be interior of $A$ if there exists $r> 0$ such that $B (x, r) \ subset A$

Comment: the border (also called edge) of a set A is the set of those points that can see points both in A and in its complement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a point $x$ of $X$ and a positive real number $\delta>0$. Let $B_{\delta}(x)$ denote the open sphere centered at $x$, with radius $\delta$, that is the set of points $y\in X$ such that $d(y,x)<\delta$. Then you can have one and only one of the following cases:

- there exists $\delta$ such that $B_{\delta}(x)$ is contained in $A$, which means that $x$ is an interior point of $A$;
- there exists $\delta$ such that $B_{\delta}(x)$ is contained in the complementary part of $A$ with respect to $X$, that is, $x$ is an interior point of $X- A$;
- for all $\delta$, both $B_{\delta}(x)\cap A$ and $B_{\delta}(x)\cap (X-A)$ are non-empty, that is, $x$ is a point which lies on the boundary of $A$

Comment: But with this we cannot conclude that it is a partition, can we?

Comment: Since the three conditions are mutually exclusive, I think the three parts of $X$ they are referring to are disjoint; moreover the set of open spheres around points of $X$ is clearly a cover of $X$.

Comment: My problem more certainly, is, as I prove that the union of the elements of the set gives me X, I cannot understand how it is concluded with the previous comment, an apology

Comment: There is a little issue with for all/there exists. The first two points should say "there exists a $\delta$ such that ... " and the third point should say "for all $\delta$, ..."